# notepad++ remove certain URL's

Tags: notepad++

I have txt file containing multiple URL's, in format:

```
url1 url2
url3 url4
url5 url6
...and so on
```

How can i remove ALL the urls on right side? I tried replacing space with \n character but that did nothing.. I  probably did it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `(space)url.+$` with nothing. But I bet (1) your URLs do not actually start with the text `url`, and (2) you don't want to remove everything after the first space of each line (it would also delete `so on` on that last line).

Comment: each url actually starts with http: //somerandomurl.com

I did (space)http:.+$ and didnt replace anything

Comment: Are you sure you have chosen Regular expressions in Search mode?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KsAHqMU.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Regular expression for Search Mode, you can find `http:((?!http\:).)*$` and replace it with nothing, it works perfectly for me:

[image]

It will match any text that start with `http:` and does not contain `http:` in the middle and the detected part should be at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the below instructions like...

Settings>>Preferences>>MISC

Now, look the "Clickable Link Settings" panel. From here just un-check both two check named as Enable and No underline.

After doing that close this preferences Window.

Now, Close and Re-open your notepad++

Hope this will helpful for you.